# How to add custom widget (with layout) overlapping another custom widget (with layout) pyqt

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, pyside2

I need to add two labels overlapping 2 QPushButton. If the user clicks on the right side of labels, they click the right button, if they click on the left side of labels, they click the left.

I hope to have something like this:

[image: expected result]

The goal is to save space for data to be displayed.

To do that I created a class which inherit from QWidget with a HBoxlayout and 2 buttons.

```
class DoublePushButton(QWidget):
    clicked = Signal(int)

    def __init__(self, **kargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kargs)

        self.data_to_display = 0

        self.right_button = QPushButton()
        self.right_button.pressed.connect(self.rightF)

        self.left_button = QPushButton()
        self.left_button.pressed.connect(self.leftF)

        self.button_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.button_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.button_layout.setSpacing(0)

        buttons = [self.left_button,self.right_button]
        for i in buttons:
            self.setButtonParam(i)
            self.button_layout.addWidget(i)

        self.setLayout(self.button_layout)

    def setButtonParam(self, button):
        button.setFlat(True)
        button.setMinimumSize(30,120)
        button.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum)

    def rightF(self):
        self.clicked.emit(1)

    def leftF(self):
        self.clicked.emit(-1)
```

Then I create 2 labels in VBoxLaout:

```
class TitleData(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,title="Title", data="Data", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title = title
        self.data = data

        self.title_label = QLabel(self.title)
        self.data_label = QLabel(self.data)
        self.title_label.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)
        self.title_label.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)
        self.data_label.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)
        self.data_label.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)

        self.l = QVBoxLayout(self.parent())
        self.l.addWidget(self.title_label)
        self.l.addWidget(self.data_label)

        self.setLayout(self.l)
```

When I try to put title_data overlapping DoublePushButton like this:

```
class DataDisplay(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.sub_widget = DoublePushButton()
        self.sub_widget.clicked.connect(self.update_data_choice)

        self.xxx = TitleData(parent=self.sub_widget)

        self.l = QVBoxLayout()
        self.l.addWidget(self.sub_widget)
        self.l.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.l.setSpacing(0)
        self.setLayout(self.l)

    def update_data_choice(self, value):
        print(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.setCentralWidget(DataDisplay())
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I get this error:
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to DoublePushButton "", which already has a layout.

And label remain invisible.

When I attempted to encapsulate DoublePushbutton in a QFrame at the end of the **init** of DoublePushButton class with this code (in replacement of self.setLayout(self.button_layout)):

```
self.f = QFrame(self.parent())
self.f.setLayout(self.button_layout)
```

Labels appear, but no buttons...

So, do you know a way to have my TitleData class overlapping DoublePushButton?

Thanks for your time, and sorry for my English.

Comment: Sorry but your whole concept seems incredibly and unnecessarily convoluted. It's not really clear if by "above" you mean *vertically* (the y axis) or *overlapping* (the z axis). Besides, a layout manager takes *complete* control of the widget it's set on (and the geometries of its children), you cannot have two or more layouts that manage the same widget: DoublePushButton already has its horizontal layout, what would you expect to happen by setting *another* layout for it in TitleData? I'd suggest you to [edit] your question and clarify all that, possibly with an image of the expected result.

Comment: @musicamante , I effectively mean overlapping. I edit the post as you suggest with this change and a picture of the expected result. 
I understand that I can't have two layouts for the same widget. What I try to do is have two layouts overlapping each over at the same place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that a widget can only have *one* layout manager, and it's not possible to set another layout if one already exists. It should also *not* be responsibility of a child widget to set the layout on a parent.

Another important aspect is that box layouts do not allow overlapping widgets, so the only solution is to use a grid layout and specify the span depending on how the overlapping widgets should be placed.

Considering the above, there are two possibilities: use the grid layout on the widget containing the buttons and add the labels on top of them, or the other way around. In the following example, I'm doing the latter. Note that in this case the widget with the labels will *not* be the child, but the parent.

```
class TitleData(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,title="Title", data="Data", buttons=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title = title
        self.data = data

        self.title_label = QLabel(self.title)
        self.data_label = QLabel(self.data)
        for label in self.title_label, self.data_label:
            label.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)
            label.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)
            label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)

        self.l = QGridLayout(self)
        self.l.addWidget(self.title_label, 0, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
        self.l.addWidget(self.data_label, 1, 0)
        self.l.setRowStretch(1, 1)
        if buttons:
            self.l.addWidget(buttons, 0, 0, 2, 1)
            buttons.lower()


class DataDisplay(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # ...
        self.xxx = TitleData(buttons=self.sub_widget)

        self.l = QVBoxLayout()
        self.l.addWidget(self.xxx)
        # ...
```

<sup>Note that the button widget is *lowered* to ensure that it's put behind the labels.</sup>

Please consider that this approach is not very good from the UX perspective, at least with the current implementation: buttons could keep a focus rectangle even if they're flat, and this could make the label difficult to read (imagine letters that have vertical lines or that could become different letters *with* a vertical line, like "o" becoming a "d" or a "b"). Creating two classes for this is also unnecessary, as you can do the same with a simple class, and you could eventually use stylesheets to improve readability:

```
class TitleDataButton(QWidget):
    clicked = pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self, title='Title', data='Data', buttons=True, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title = title
        self.data = data

        self.title_label = QLabel(self.title)
        self.data_label = QLabel(self.data)
        for label in self.title_label, self.data_label:
            label.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)
            label.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)
            label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.title_label, 0, 0, 1, 2, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
        layout.addWidget(self.data_label, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.setRowStretch(1, 1)

        if buttons:
            self.right_button = QPushButton()
            self.right_button.pressed.connect(self.rightF)
            self.left_button = QPushButton()
            self.left_button.pressed.connect(self.leftF)

            for c, button in enumerate((self.left_button, self.right_button)):
                layout.addWidget(button, 0, c, 2, 1)
                button.setMinimumSize(30,120)
                button.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
                button.lower()
                button.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)

                button.setStyleSheet('''
                    QPushButton {
                        border: 1px solid transparent;
                        border-radius: 2px;
                    }
                    QPushButton:hover {
                        border-color: darkGray;
                        background: lightGray;
                    }
                    QPushButton:pressed {
                        background: darkGray;
                    }
                ''')

    def rightF(self):
        self.clicked.emit(1)

    def leftF(self):
        self.clicked.emit(-1)
```

<sup>As above, the buttons are lowered so that they're placed under the labels.</sup>